# How to invert the axis of a seaborn figure-level plot (FacetGrid)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, relplot

I would like to invert the y-axis in each plot of a Facetgrid.

Below you find a reduced example of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'a':['yes', 'no']*5, 'b':np.arange(10), 'c':np.arange(10)*2})
plt.figure()
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df_test, row='a')
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, y='c', x='b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As far as I know, this is normally done with `ax.invert_yaxis()` when using matplotlib, so I tried to access it through `g.axes` but had no luck.

I am aware that I can manually set a `ylim=(max_val, min_val)`, however, this results in unsightly tick spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Extract and set each axes, by iterating through `g.axes`
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df_test, row='a')
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, y='c', x='b')

for ax in g.axes[0]:
    ax.invert_yaxis()
```

- However, directly using [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) is not recommended. Use the figure-level plot [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) with `kind='scatter'`

```py
g = sns.relplot(data=df_test, row='a', x='b', y='c', kind='scatter', height=3)
for ax in g.axes[0]:
    ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

- Use `.ravel()` to flatten `n x n` arrays or `axes`, where both `n > 1`

```py
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'a':['yes', 'no', 'maybe']*4, 'b':np.arange(12), 'c':np.arange(12)*2, 'd': np.arange(12)*3})

g = sns.relplot(data=df_test, col='a', col_wrap=2, x='b', y='c', kind='scatter', height=3)
for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciated Trenton! Also, the further tip to ditch Facetgrid :)

Comment: @Cider You're welcome. Glad this works for you.